# Defining the Transport Fleet capacity via a schedule slows down simulation run drastically

Tags: anylogic

I built up a small simulation model which shall represent the transportation of trolleys between two floors (level 1 and level 2), which are connected with a lift. Each of the levels has a node and a lift space markup. All elements are connected with paths.

I use a source to inject agents (material item) into a queue (node at Level 2) with a fixed rate. Using a moveByTransporter block and a TransportFleet, those agents are moved via lift to a second queue (node at level 1). This works fine. 
After I have implemented a schedule in order to change the TransportFleet capacity to represent a shift pattern I noticed, that the simulation speed decreases drastically after the capacity value switches back and forth. I already deleted the schedule and tried to use events, but this approach led to the same problem.

The model time unit is hours.

How to solve this problem?

EDIT_1:

I set up the schedule the following way (please find attached a snapshot):

Type: integer,
The schedule defines: Intervals (Start, End),
Duration type: Week,
Default value: 0, Repeat schedule weekly: each day marked, Start: 6:00 AM, End: 2:00 PM, no exceptions.

[schedule configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEQZe.png)

EDIT_2:

The capacity value of the TransporterFleet fluctuates between 0 and 1 Transporters. [TransporterFleet configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FZCb.png)

Additionally you can find the event list for the first shift (Transporter is available): [Transporter is available: Model and Event List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgaZB.png)

and for the time after the first shift (Transporter is unavailable): [Transporter is unavailable: Model and Event List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diDAW.png).

In the last snapshots you can see as well, how the simulated time per second drops from ~30 to 8.

Comment: Well, how do you setup the schedule? :-)

Comment: Please find the schedule configuration under my original post (just added it there).

Comment: cool. How large is the fluctuation in transporters? Does it go from 0 to 100? (Transporters are relatively heavy on computation). It is unlikely to be the schedule itself

Comment: Hi Benjamin, just added some information in the original post. There is either only  one or no transporter.

Comment: Your detail and screenshots just show that the simulated speed differs between when the transporter pool has capacity 0 vs. capacity 1 (not comparing using a capacity schedule vs. not using one). That is a little strange but will depend on AnyLogic's internal implementation (i.e., it's not necessarily a 'problem/error' though it could be....)